# Why does running dir(asyncio) from a python file does not give the same out as running from interactive shell?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.8

My project interpreter is python3.8
My code:

```
import asyncio
print(dir(asyncio))
```

Writing above code to a file and running that file produces this ouput:

```
['ChainMap', 'Counter', 'OrderedDict', 'UserDict', 'UserList', 'UserString', '_Link', '_OrderedDictItemsView', '_OrderedDictKeysView', '_OrderedDictValuesView', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__getattr__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_chain', '_collections_abc', '_count_elements', '_eq', '_heapq', '_iskeyword', '_itemgetter', '_proxy', '_recursive_repr', '_repeat', '_starmap', '_sys', '_tuplegetter', 'defaultdict', 'deque', 'namedtuple']
['ChainMap', 'Counter', 'OrderedDict', 'UserDict', 'UserList', 'UserString', '_Link', '_OrderedDictItemsView', '_OrderedDictKeysView', '_OrderedDictValuesView', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__getattr__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_chain', '_collections_abc', '_count_elements', '_eq', '_heapq', '_iskeyword', '_itemgetter', '_proxy', '_recursive_repr', '_repeat', '_starmap', '_sys', '_tuplegetter', 'defaultdict', 'deque', 'namedtuple']
```

Notice i get the same list twice

now when i try the above code in interactive shell i get:

```
['ALL_COMPLETED', 'AbstractChildWatcher', 'AbstractEventLoop', 'AbstractEventLoopPolicy', 'AbstractServer', 'BaseEventLoop', 'BaseProtocol', 'BaseTransport', 'BoundedSemaphore', 'BufferedProtocol', 'CancelledError', 'Condition', 'DatagramProtocol', 'DatagramTransport', 'DefaultEventLoopPolicy', 'Event', 'FIRST_COMPLETED', 'FIRST_EXCEPTION', 'FastChildWatcher', 'Future', 'Handle', 'IncompleteReadError', 'InvalidStateError', 'LifoQueue', 'LimitOverrunError', 'Lock', 'MultiLoopChildWatcher', 'PriorityQueue', 'Protocol', 'Queue', 'QueueEmpty', 'QueueFull', 'ReadTransport', 'SafeChildWatcher', 'SelectorEventLoop', 'Semaphore', 'SendfileNotAvailableError', 'StreamReader', 'StreamReaderProtocol', 'StreamWriter', 'SubprocessProtocol', 'SubprocessTransport', 'Task', 'ThreadedChildWatcher', 'TimeoutError', 'TimerHandle', 'Transport', 'WriteTransport', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_all_tasks_compat', '_enter_task', '_get_running_loop', '_leave_task', '_register_task', '_set_running_loop', '_unregister_task', 'all_tasks', 'as_completed', 'base_events', 'base_futures', 'base_subprocess', 'base_tasks', 'constants', 'coroutine', 'coroutines', 'create_subprocess_exec', 'create_subprocess_shell', 'create_task', 'current_task', 'ensure_future', 'events', 'exceptions', 'format_helpers', 'futures', 'gather', 'get_child_watcher', 'get_event_loop', 'get_event_loop_policy', 'get_running_loop', 'iscoroutine', 'iscoroutinefunction', 'isfuture', 'locks', 'log', 'new_event_loop', 'open_connection', 'open_unix_connection', 'protocols', 'queues', 'run', 'run_coroutine_threadsafe', 'runners', 'selector_events', 'set_child_watcher', 'set_event_loop', 'set_event_loop_policy', 'shield', 'sleep', 'sslproto', 'staggered', 'start_server', 'start_unix_server', 'streams', 'subprocess', 'sys', 'tasks', 'transports', 'trsock', 'unix_events', 'wait', 'wait_for', 'wrap_future']
```

Why is the output different in the two cases?

Comment: Your first output looks more like the contents of `collections`.  I couldn't reproduce this, you may have another file with the name `asyncio.py` somewhere that is interfering with the import.  The second print also doesn't make sense with just the code here.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHaugh you are bang on right. i had a different file with the asyncio.py file. So silly of me..